# Unable to install libgtk2. Connection refusing

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, ppa, launchpad

I am trying to install libgtk2 using command

```
 sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

but, I am receiving following message (`403 Forbidden`):

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/accessibility-dev/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main  libatk1.0-dev amd64 2.18.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1   403 Forbidden 
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/accessibility-dev/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/a/atk1.0/libatk1.0-dev_2.18.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden 
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `accessibility-dev` user account on Launchpad does no longer exist. Their [user page](https://launchpad.net/~accessibility-dev) shows a "Page not found" as well.

Their user page was last indexed by the Internet Archive Wayback Machine in March 2016 ([visit archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322085747/https://launchpad.net/~accessibility-dev)), so probably the account got deleted.

This means however that their PPA which you have installed also does no longer exist and will never come back, so you should remove it from your list of software sources.

Ubuntu has a version of the `libgtk2.0-dev` package [in its own main repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgtk2.0-dev) as well though, so you don't need a PPA at all. Simply install it from the command-line after removing the obsolete PPA and updating your lists:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:accessibility-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```